How can I use a pattern of every nth row reference from another sheet in Excel?
I'm making a sheet that is referencing another sheet.  The reference sheet is blocks of data that repeat every 25 rows.
for details:
I want the first cell reference to be: =IF(RFA!B40>0,RFA!B40,"")
in the next row down same column I set it to =IF(RFA!B65>0,RFA!B65,"")  (25 difference)
Id like to repeat this pattern down 22 rows.  when I select 1 field and drag down it goes down by one (40, 41, 42, etc)
If I select the 2 original fields with the formula and drag down, the third row goes to 42 and the 4th goes to 67.
What I want it to do is this:
=IF(Sheet1!A45="","",Sheet1!A45)
=IF(Sheet1!A60="","",Sheet1!A60)
=IF(Sheet1!A75="","",Sheet1!A85)
=IF(Sheet1!A90="","",Sheet1!A110)

...
Is this possible? How could I accomplish it?

If you have access to WRAPROWS() then can use the following formula, and one doesn't needs to copy down, as it will spill for the whole array:


=TAKE(WRAPROWS(RFA!A40:A90,15),,1)


Or, Older Versions can use:
=IFERROR(INDEX(RFA!A$40:A$90,COLUMN(A1)+(ROW(A1)-1)*15),"")



Using INDEX and some math:
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*15+45)="","",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*15+45))

Then when it is dragged down the row multiplier changes and the next reference is 15 rows below.

You can use indirect if you want to reference cell dynamically. its a great tool to add to your mental toolbox if you understand how it works!
for example use this formula:
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()*15)="","",INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()*15))
Start in row 3 (for example A3) and drag it down
for the purists you can start in cell A2 but this makes the formula slighty more compicated:
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & (ROW()*15)+15 )="","",INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & (ROW()*15)+15 )
